# Not correct jvm is used

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I created a spring boot 3 application splitted in 3 parts. Common is used by both.

```
lcm
  Intranet
  Extranet
  Common
```

At lcm root i launch this

```
.\gradlew.bat build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=C:\zulu17.40.19-ca-jdk17.0.6-win_x64
```

Build gradle a the lcm root

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.acme.lcm-backend'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}
```

I get this error
A problem occurred configuring root project 'lcm-backend'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.6.
> Required by:
> project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.6
> > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.6 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.6 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8

I specify correct jvm, I don't understand why I get this issue